# Find all text occurrences between <h2></h2>

Tags: php

I want to auto generate a table of content out of a html string with all h2 headings and need to put them in an array for that reason.

I have a $text string with the formatted html inside:

```
<h2>heading 1</h2>
<p>something</p>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<p>something</p>
<h2>heading 3</h2>
<p>something</p>
```

How can I extract all the headings inside h2 into an array?

I found out that I need regex, maybe preg_match_all.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
preg_match_all("<h2>(.*?)</h2>", $text, $found);
print_r($found);
```

Thanks for any help for a beginner!

Comment: You are missing the delimiters in your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Regex to

```
preg_match_all('#<h2.*?>(.*?)</h2>#i',$text, $found);
```

Explanation

```
<h2.*?> - ignore the classes/attributes in the tag if any
(.*?)   - capture everything
</h2>   - match end tag
i       - ignore case
```

Then Loop through Array and print values

```
foreach ($found[1] as $a) 
  echo $a." ";
```